# Rails Minitest, view output from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a simple method to test my `index` action in one of my Rails controllers.  In minitest, it sends a request to `GET /{resource}` like `get :index, format: :json`.

In my controller action for `index` I have a few lines that `puts some_var`.  How can I view this output from the controller action when running the test from the command line?

It is output when sending a request to the server, but doesn't appear when running the test from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You want: [assert_output](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/Minitest%2FAssertions%3Aassert_output)

controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
```

test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test 'outputs hello' do
    assert_output(/hello/) do # use regex because "hello" will fail per http://stackoverflow.com/a/26855137/46076
      post :bar
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution does not work. The output from _within_ the controller is not captured in that assertion method.